# python gtk module opens display on import

Tags: python, gtk

I'm using the trick "python -c 'import myscript.py'" to perform a syntax check on a script which uses 'import gtk'.

I get the following error when performing the syntax check, which implies that the gtk module is executing a check for the X display, even though all that's being done at this point is to import the module.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 15, in ?

      File "myscript.py", line 21, in ?

    import gtk

  File "/usr/src/build/463937-i386/install/usr/lib/python2.3/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py", line 37, in ?

RuntimeError: could not open display
```

Is there a way to avoid this error when performing the syntax check?

Before you ask - I'm not able to set $DISPLAY before the syntax check is run.  The check is being run on remote servers as part of a distributed build system.  These servers do not have an X display available.

Answer (score 3):

*Importing modules in Python executes their code!*
Well-behaved modules use the `if __name__ == '__main__'` trick to avoid side effects, but they can still fail - as happened to you.

[BTW, getting to ImportError means the whole file already has correct syntax.]

If you just want to check syntax, without running at all:

- `python -m py_compile my_script.py`
  will check one file (and produce a `.pyc` as a side effect).
- `python -m compileall ./`
  will check a whole dir recursively.
- `python -c 'compile(open("myscript.py").read(), "myscript.py", "exec")'`
  avoids creating a `.pyc`.

But note that merely checking the syntax in Python catches very few bugs!  Importing does catch more, e.g. mispelled names.  For even better checks, use [tools like Pychecker / Pyflakes](http://pycheesecake.org/wiki/PythonTestingToolsTaxonomy#SourceCodeCheckingTools).

Comment: +1 for pointing to checker tools! I would recommend [flake8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flake8), though.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by `'syntax checking'`?
Can't you use a tool like [pylint](http://www.logilab.org/857) to check for syntax errors?

Otherwise: a very ugly (but probably possible hack):

1. In your python script detect whether X is present.
2. If it's not => use [GTK on DirectFramebuffer](http://www.directfb.org/wiki/index.php/Projects:GTK_on_DirectFB) (no X needed then). You'll need to compile GTK on DirectFB (and/or pygtk) from source ([some pointers here](http://old.nabble.com/pygtk-with-directfb-without-x11-td24289652.html)).

Answer (score 0):

If the remote machine has vncserver installed, you can have a dummy server running and connect to that. Sample instructions:

```
remotemachine $ vncserver -depth 16 -geometry 800x600 :7
New 'X' desktop is remotemachine:7

Starting applications specified in /home/user/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/user/.vnc/userve:7.log
remotemachine $ DISPLAY=:7 python -c 'import myscript.py'
…
remotemachine $ vncserver -kill :7
Killing Xtightvnc process ID 32058
```

Comment: The X.Org distribution ships `Xvfb` and `Xfake`, which can be used for similar purposes.  Also, I'd probably use `startx \`which python\` -c myscript.py -- \`which Xvnc\` :7`, which will automatically set up the environment for the client and teardown the X server once it's done.

Comment: @ephemient: Based on the question information, I assumed that there isn't any X.Org installation in the remote servers.

Comment: Right, but the UNIX VNC server contains port of X.Org anyhow.  If OP needs X.Org parts, it doesn't matter which parts they are as long as they work; there's nothing particularly special about `Xvnc`.

Comment: I don't know why you need to say the obvious: "there's nothing special about Xvnc" and whether there is shared code between Xvnc and X.Org. I'm trying to re-read my texts to see if, perhaps, I come through as believing that Xvnc is a panacea for all server and administrator issues. Instead, I think that between X.Org and Xvnc an administrator would *obviously* select Xvnc just for its smaller package size, *assuming both are not installed*, and that is why I can't understand what's the issue you're insisting on.

Comment: The Xvnc sources contain a copy of the X.Org xserver; Xfake and Xvfb are built from a subset of the X.Org xserver.  Either way, there is no need to install the entire X.Org distribution, and `apt-get install [vncserver/xvfb/...]` or whatever is appropriate for OP's system will probably pull down the minimal bits required.  If OP has PyGTK, all the required X client library bits are installed anyways, so a lot of the X.Org distribution is already present.

Comment: OK, thanks. Hopefully one can install a small subset of X.Org+Xfake/Xvfb that is size-wise comparable to Xvnc. I won't update my answer, though, since this isn't something that I personally know/tested.

Answer (score 0):

In your myscript.py, you could do like this

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    import gtk
```

That will not execute gtk's `__init__.py` when you do `"python -c 'import myscript.py'"`

Comment: But if the script accesses anything in `gtk.` outside of functions (e.g. inherits from a gtk class), it will fail with a NameError.

Answer (score 0):

If you are editing with IDLE, **Alt+X** will check syntax of current file without running it.